# How to process the data returned from a function (Python 3.7)

Tags: python-3.x, function, statistics

Background:
My question should be relatively easy, however I am not able to figure it out. 
I have written a function regarding queueing theory and it will be used for ambulance service planning. For example, how many calls for service can I expect in a given time frame. 
The function takes two parameters; a starting value of the number of ambulances in my system starting at 0 and ending at 100 ambulances. This will show the probability of zero calls for service, one call for service, three calls for service….up to 100 calls for service. Second parameter is an arrival rate number which is the past historical arrival rate in my system. 
The function runs and prints out the result to my screen. I have checked the math and it appears to be correct.

This is Python 3.7 with the Anaconda distribution.

My question is this:
I would like to process this data even further but I don’t know how to capture it and do more math. For example, I would like to take this list and accumulate the probability values. With an arrival rate of five, there is a cumulative probability of 61.56% of at least five calls for service, etc.

A second example of how I would like to process this data is to format it as percentages and write out a text file

A third example would be to process the cumulative probabilities and exclude any values higher than the 99% cumulative value (because these vanish into extremely small numbers).

A fourth example would be to create a bar chart showing the probability of n calls for service.

These are some of the things I want to do with the queueing theory calculations. And there are a lot more. I am planning on writing a larger application. But I am stuck at this point. The function writes an output into my Python 3.7 console. How do I “capture” that output as an object or something and perform other processing on  the data?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import math
import csv

def probability_x(start_value = 0, arrival_rate = 0):
    probability_arrivals = []
    while start_value  <= 100:
        probability_arrivals = [start_value, math.pow(arrival_rate, start_value) * math.pow(math.e, -arrival_rate) / math.factorial(start_value)]
        print(probability_arrivals)
        start_value = start_value + 1
    return probability_arrivals

#probability_x(arrival_rate = 5, x = 5)

#The code written above prints to the console, but my goal is to take the returned values and make other calculations. 
#How do I 'capture' this data for further processing is where I need help (for example, bar plots, cumulative frequency, etc )

#failure. TypeError: writerows() argument must be iterable. 
with open('ExpectedProbability.csv', 'w') as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
    for value in probability_x(arrival_rate = 5):
        writer.writerows(value)
writeFile.close()

#Failure. Why does it return 2. Yes there are two columns but I was expecting 101 as the length because that is the end of my loop.
print(len(probability_x(arrival_rate = 5)))
```

Comment: You should try to make this question far more terse and narrow. It seems like there's too much background unrelated to your exact question, and I don't see a clear problem statement. It isn't readily clear what the problem is that you're asking about.

Comment: "Why does it return 2": You're constantly overwriting `probability_arrivals` in the loop. Did you mean to `append` instead of overwriting the old data with `=`?

Comment: The data prints out on the screen as: 0,     0.00673 second line is 1,    0.033689 third line as 2,    0.084224. My goal is to take this data and process it even further. But how do I take hold of this data in Python to do further analysis on it?

Comment: Any data that you want to use should be returned from the function. As I said in my previous comment, I think you meant to `append ` to `probability_arrivals` instead of overwriting it once per loop. Something like `probability_arrivals.append([start_value, math.pow(arrival_rate, start_value) * math.pow(math.e, -arrival_rate) / math.factorial(start_value)])`. You're currently printing out the data but not returning all of it. You're only returning the final value.

Comment: Then, once you're properly returning all the data, you can do `x = probability_x(2, 4)`, then use `x` to do whatever you want.

Comment: Carcigenicate: Thank you for all your help. The proper way to do this is as you mention: The corrected line of code is: probability_arrivals.append([start_value, math.pow(arrival_rate, start_value) * math.pow(math.e, -arrival_rate) / math.factorial(start_value)])    Notice the code changed to probability_arrivals.append

Comment: Carcigenicate: How do I mark your contribution as the proper answer? Thereby closing the issue.

Comment: I posted an answer that can be accepted, and made a suggestion at the bottom re: the loop. Once you have this code working, you can post the complete runnable code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions) along with a description of what it does, and we can help make further suggestions if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, when you write

```
probability_arrivals = [start_value, math.pow(arrival_rate, start_value) * math.pow(math.e, -arrival_rate) / math.factorial(start_value)]
```

You're overwriting the previous contents of `probability_arrivals`. Everything that it held previously is lost.

Instead of using `=` to reassign `probability_arrivals`, you want to `append` another entry to the list:

```
probability_arrivals.append([start_value, math.pow(arrival_rate, start_value) * math.pow(math.e, -arrival_rate) / math.factorial(start_value)])
```

---

I'll also note, your `while` loop can be improved. You're basically just looping over `start_value` until it reaches a certain value. A `for` loop would be more appropriate here:

```
for s in range(start_value, 101):  # The end value is exclusive, so it's 101 not 100
    probability_arrivals = [s, math.pow(arrival_rate, s) * math.pow(math.e, -arrival_rate) / math.factorial(s)]
    print(probability_arrivals)
```

Now you don't need to manually worry about incrementing the counter.